# Is there a way to return select query results with few column's value as NULL (other than using REPLACE)?

Tags: sql, db2

I want to export a table in DB2 where in which I want to return few column vaues as NULL due to some restrictions. 
I am looking for better alternatives to prepare the select query for export.

I can achieve it with the below select query. But the query is very long considering the table has many columns.

```
SELECT

COL1
,COL2
,COL3
,COL4

,REPLACE(COL5,NULL) AS COL5

,REPLACE(COL6,NULL) AS COL6

,COL7
,COL8
,COL9
,COL10
,COL11

,REPLACE(COL12,NULL) AS COL12

,COL13
,COL14
,COL15
,COL16
,COL17
,COL18

,REPLACE(COL19,NULL) AS COL19

,COL20

FROM
TABLE1
```

Is there any better alternatives?

Comment: Why not just use `NULL AS COL5` rather than `REPLACE(COL5, NULL) AS COL5`?

Comment: Yes, this can be done. Still looking if there is a way to simplify as the number of columns in the table are more and there is a need to select all the columns to replace few column's value as NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following way to set column null value

```
SELECT 
    COL1
    ,COL2
    ,COL3
    ,COL4
    ,NULL AS COL5,
    ,NULL AS COL6      
FROM TABLE1
```